# A weird error in Matlab with MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, matlab

I have two tables named t1 and t2, which content list as following:

```
mysql> use test;
Database changed
mysql> select * from t1;
+----+------+
| id | val  |
+----+------+
|  1 |  100 |
|  2 |  200 |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t2;
+----+-------+
| id | val   |
+----+-------+
| -1 | -1000 |
|  1 |  1000 |
|  3 |  3000 |
+----+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

There is a sql statement run in mysql command with on problem:

```
mysql> create or replace view iid as select id from t1 union select id from t2;select iid.id,t1.val,t2.val from iid left join t1 on iid.id=t1.id left join t2 on iid.id=t2.id;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

+----+------+-------+
| id | val  | val   |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 |  100 |  1000 |
|  2 |  200 |  NULL |
| -1 | NULL | -1000 |
|  3 | NULL |  3000 |
+----+------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

While it run in matlab with a error:

```
>> sqlCmd = ['create or replace view iid as select id from t1 union select id from t2;',...
          'select iid.id,t1.val,t2.val from iid',...
          ' left join t1 on iid.id=t1.id',...
          ' left join t2 on iid.id=t2.id'];

conn = database('test','root','198471',...
        'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver','jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test');
>> curs = exec(conn,sqlCmd);
>> curs.Message
ans =
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select iid.id,t1.val,t2.val from iid left join t1 on iid.id=t1.id left join t2 o' at line 1
>> curs = exec(conn,'select * from t1');
>> curs = fetch(curs);
>> curs.Data
ans =
     1   100
     2   200
>> sqlCmd
```

I'm a pure newbie of SQL, and I have no idea for this error message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The semicolon delimits two separate SQL statements.  In the MySQL command-line client, multiple statements can be given on one line and they will be executed sequentially (as a "batch").  I assume that you will either need to enable batched statements in MATLAB/your JDBC driver or else send each statement independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that Matlab treats each string in your `sqlCmd` matrix as a separate SQL statment. As you are breaking up the queries into string portions this will not work, because each not every portion is a valid standalone SQL statement. As the comment above suggests, you may need to search for a setting that allows this. Alternatively you could try to rewrite your SQL into a single string just like you did with mysql:

```
 sqlCmd = 'create or replace view iid as select id from t1 union select id from t2;select iid.id,t1.val,t2.val from iid left join t1 on iid.id=t1.id left join t2 on iid.id=t2.id;';
 curs = exec(conn,sqlCmd);
```

This should at least run your query without error. If you have not done so already, take a look at the mathworks documentation for `exec` http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/database/ug/exec.html